# Dependency resolving design pattern

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, module

I am looking for a php implementation or a design pattern something like this (just a very basic skeleton example):

```
namespace Contract {
    interface Application {...}
    interface EntryPoint {...}
}

namespace RestApi {

    class Module {
        /** @return Contract\EntryPoint */
        public function getEntryPoint(Contract\Application $application){...}
    }

    class EntryPoint implements Contract\EntryPoint {...}
}

namespace BusinessLogic {

    class Module {
        /** @return Contract\Application */
        public function getApplication(){...}
    }

    class Application implements Contract\Application {...}
}

$dependencyResolver = new DependencyResolver();
$dependencyResolver->parse(new RestApi\Module());
$dependencyResolver->parse(new BusinessLogic\Module());
$dependencyResolver->invoke(function (Contract\EntryPoint $entryPoint){
    $entrypoint->handleRequest();
});
```

I want to loose couple every modules I am using in my application, so I intend to design interfaces, maybe abstract classes with validation to make a well defined interface for every module type. I haven't found a solution for this problem, ppl usually inject things with IoC container, which does not tell anything about the common interface between two modules...

Do you know a design pattern which solves this problem, or a de factor standard php implementation/framework for this?

*note: IoC container is not a solution, I want to inject the dependencies with well defined interfaces, not to pull them from a DI container or service locator... I don't want my modules to know anything about how they get their dependencies...*

**edit:**

I updated my question because I don't think my code was obvious for everyone. A created a class diagram to ease the understanding of it:

[image: class diagram of multiple modules in one of the environments]

Okay, so this diagram contains a description of a single environment. We usually use different environments for example: test, development, production, etc... Each of these environment contains different modules, for example by testing and developing we usually turn off email sending, so one of the modules contains a mock php mailer in those environments... As you see by cross-module dependency the classes depend on contracts, not directly on each other. This way the code of the modules is loose coupled...

[image: dependency between the participants of contracts]

I intend to describe this dependencies (for example with annotations) and inject them on an automated way somehow. This is a difficult task, because by PHP I have to load only the classes which are necessary to handle the request. For example:

[image: loading only the necessary dependencies]

So I have to use lazy load somehow, for example I could inject factories, but I don't like that idea, I want to inject the dependency itself, not a factory...

Be aware that the contract interface does not know anything about its implementations, so I have to publish somehow those implementations by every module and find them from the other modules... Most of the DI container implementations solve that problem, but I don't want to inject factories or DI containers into my modules. I want them to depend on the contracts only and nothing else...

**Matthieu Napoli** recommended to use just a single IoC container with different config by each of the environments, but I don't see how this would solve my problem. That DI container would instantiate every class with cross-module dependency, so I would move the whole config of every modules into a huge main config file. Even by a simple project I'd have about 20 classes (languages, users, identification-factors, user-identification-factors, contacts, user-contacts, roles, user-roles, permissions, role-permissions, articles, comments, etc...) and at least 3 modules (presentation layer, business logic layer, data access layer). So that main config would contain the instantiation of at least 60 classes from different modules... That would be pretty hard to maintain and I am almost certain that it would result a lot of code repetition by configs of different environments... Yes maybe splitting the config files can reduce the pain, but I guess I wont know the advantages and drawbacks of this solution until I start to use it on a complicated project. Another problem with this approach that how should I implement the lazy load without injecting the IoC container itself into every class with cross-module dependency? I think I need proof or example code, that this approach really works well by this problem domain...

Currently I am thinking on something similar than require.js does with AMD javascript modules, but that injects the IoC container as well by lazy load. You have to use the `require("moduleName")` from inside the modules if you want to load a dependency which you don't want to use in your code, just in case when it's really necessary. Ofc that `require` is just a sugar syntax of `container.get("moduleName")`... Currently I don't see how to solve that problem. I think every of my modules should have one or more DI containers, call them module containers. Those module containers can handle the cross-module dependencies. By lazy load the module containers would pull down the cross-module dependencies of each class from a main container, which would automatically register every module container and every class instantiated by them. In this scenario only the module containers would know about the main container if I cannot solve lazy load without injecting a factory or a DI container or a service locator... Ofc this is the last resort, I think I can do the lazy load somehow without injecting the main container into the module containers. Or at least I can do it somehow with a sugar syntax, for example:

```
class ModuleContainer {
    public function setCrossDomainDependency(Contract\Dep $crossDomainDependency){
        //...
    }

    /** @return Contract\Dep */
    public function getCrossDomainDependency(){
        //...
    }
}
```

My purpose to use the same `ModuleContainer` instance regardless of having a `MainContainer`. I'll check the reflection api, maybe I am able to override the `getCrossDomainDependency` somehow at runtime. If not then I think the only solution to inject factories or the main container... Nah but this is my solution...

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: I think you are creating problems that do not exist. I work on a large app with many modules, and each module has its config. Same in the Symfony world: each Bundle has its own config, period. Same in ZF2 too. Having several containers is just another way to separate things, but I don't see any difference at all except that is more complex to maintain and develop.

Comment: Maybe it is more complex to implement DI containers manually as I do, but I have code autocompletion and full refactoring support, so it is very easy to maintain my containers...
There is a big difference between the global containers and these local ones; I can control the external dependencies of a module this way. So I can write integration tests for every module very easily...
I have a beta code currently. I will test it with a small project, and after that I will push it to github and share the link here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A IoC container is *exactly* the solution.

> I want to inject the dependencies with well defined interfaces, not to pull them from a DI container or service locator

Then don't use the container as a service locator. That's exactly what a DI container is meant for.

Here is your example using [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/):

```
$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
$container = containerBuilder->build();

// Configure RestApi\EntryPoint to use for Contract\EntryPoint
$container->set(Contract\EntryPoint::class, \DI\link(RestApi\EntryPoint::class));

// Configure BusinessLogic\Application to use for Contract\Application
$container->set(Contract\Application::class, \DI\link(BusinessLogic\Application::class));

// Run
$entryPoint = $container->get(Contract\EntryPoint::class);
$entryPoint->handleRequest();
```

Of course my example here is not perfect. I would suggest to separate the configuration part from the execution part. I would put the configuration in a configuration file ([look here for how](http://php-di.org/doc/definition.html)).

**Important**: Yes, in that example I fetch something from the container. That is exceptional. That should happen only once or twice in your application.

You have to use the container at some point, at the root of your application (i.e. the entry point of the app), to construct the object graph (or dependency graph).

I am not suggesting that you call `get()` on the container everytime you need a dependency. I am suggesting that you use dependency injection instead, and that you call `get()` only at the entry point of the application.

---

Example of defining with a factory:

```
$container->set(Contract\EntryPoint::class, \DI\factory(function (Container $c) {
    return new RestApi\EntryPoint($c->get('some.parameter'));
}));
```

Comment: Don't you find using interface names as strings disgusting?

Comment: Yes I do :) I didn't want to complicate the example but I use PHP 5.5, which PHP-DI was built for (see the home page http://php-di.org/). I'll update my example with `::class`

Comment: I guess I cannot avoid the `invoke` part in my code, so my version is just a sntax sugar for a DI container. I will think about it.

Comment: Example updated. Why can't you call the `handleRequest` directly?

Comment: Because the `public function getEntryPoint(Contract\Application $application){...}` does the instantiation of the `EntryPoint`. That would contain a `get((BusinessLogic\Application::class)` in your code. So it is not so simple scenario... ;-)

Comment: Ahh no problem then, you can define an entry in the container using a `factory` (i.e. a callable). Have a look at http://php-di.org/doc/definition.html

Comment: Ye I understand. So you suggest I'd use a DI container, for example PHP-DI, Pimple, etc... I will think about this... I try to avoid inject a container into my modules, but it is hard to achieve lazy load without that. If I don't find a solution, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Do not inject the container anywhere! Always inject dependencies only.  PHP-DI and several other containers offers lazy injection (not Pimple though).

Comment: I don't think you understand the whole problem. In my current code every `Module` class is a handmade DI container. I need something over those Container-s, which sends the dependencies from one `Module` to another.

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: Yepp, that is similar to my intent with my `invoke` function and any method which is in a `Module` class. I write a little more about my problem. Imagine, that the `Contract` contains about 100 interfaces. It would be very hard to put the all in a single DI Container... Which I intend to do is splitting that container into subcontainers. Every `Module` class is a subcontainer which describes which contract is implementation is instantiated by the module, and which contract implementation it needs from another module... This kind of logic depends on the environment: dev, test, production, etc.

Comment: Related issue for 100 interfaces: https://github.com/mnapoli/PHP-DI/issues/156 (TL/DR: no real solution for now). And regarding dev, test, prod, I usually write a main config file, and one config file per environment to override as needed.

Comment: So I need a DI Container over DI Containers, which should not just call factories, but know that which factory provides an instance of a class which implements an exact interface... So it is not so simple as you think...

Comment: Why don't you just have 1 container and several config files? That's how I do it: 1 configuration per module (so that each module register its services and parameters), and also a global config too for general stuff.

Comment: Yes, this is really a related issue. It cannot solve without using Annotations... I use them in the sub-containers...

Comment: Technically that's just a partial solution... I'd do the same by parsing the sub-containers and their annotations with the reflection api...

Comment: The problem, that I cannot solve is lazy loading... When I want to load a dependency from outside of one sub-container in runtime... In order to do that, I have to inject the main container or another subcontainer... Or I can do the whole map in a very long config file, but that would result maintainability issues...

Comment: Split your files? I still don't understand what advantage you see at having several containers.

Comment: I've seen your edit, and I don't understand why in your head "split your config into several files" == "I will have a HUGE config file"???

Comment: Can you show me a project that faces with the same problem and solves it with a single DI container which loads multiple config files?

Comment: Any Symfony 2 or Zend Framework 2 app. I don't have a link for you, my projects are private. Anyway, do what you want, you'll get your own experience.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check them. Learning from existing code is always easier than develop a new solution for the problem...